# Line and column combo chart with multiple columns for each category, how to position line marker for each category on a specific column?

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart that looks like the below. The line is a rolling average of the third column from each category. I would like to position the marker for the line in the middle of the green/yellow column rather than the middle of the black, for each category. Is this possible?

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pointPlacement` property:

```
series: [..., {
  pointPlacement: 0.2,
  ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4810/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointPlacement